# Very small sample size alternative to binary response logistic regression for evaluating single-species habitat associations

Tags: logistic, t-test, chi-squared-test, binary-data, continuous-data

I'm interested in evaluating the relative importance of different habitat variables on presence/absence of a particular species in habitat patches. I was limited to surveying 20ish sites on account of logistical considerations, which precludes using logistic regression (already tried it and Firth logistic regression).

The most straightforward alternative I can think of is simply running multiple two sample t-tests/Mann-Whitney tests and chi square tests between present and absent site samples (for continuous and categorical variables respectively) since the species was detected at roughly half the sites. I would correct for multiple testing using something like the Bonferroni correction. The wishful interpretation would be variables that differ most significantly between present and absent site groups could potentially impact habitat selection more strongly.

I recognize that these tests are generally used for descriptive purposes rather than inferring causation. Also, this method wouldn't be informative as to additive effects of different variables or interactions between variables.

What other limitations are there to this approach and interpretations of its results? Are there better alternatives in this case?

EDIT: I should clarify that sites are discrete ponds selected systematically and many of the habitat variables were measured manually rather than collected from existing databases, so I'm not sure whether species distribution modeling would be appropriate.